# Name of Polynomial form without substitution

Tags: polynomials, terminology

Fairly simple question here, what is the name of a polynomial where the values/substitution don't matter, only the value of the coefficients and exponents?

For example, the polynomial could take any shape:

$1+2x^2$

$x^3+4x^5+8x+10$

the defining characteristic is that no number is substituted for x.

Comment: If you need to be explicit, you can call it a formal polynomial. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216470/207316 & https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98345/207316

Comment: Then it's just a "polynomial", which can be very different from a "polynomial function" depending on the field you're working with (with finite field for example there is no longer a bijection between the two categories). $X$ is usually called the " indeterminate ". Formally, a polynomial is defined as a sequence which has only a finite number of non-zero terms.

Comment: It helped if you quoted what your definition of a polynomial is.