# Is the notation $X^2$ an abuse of language in a polynomial ring?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I wonder if the notation

$$ P(X) = a_{0} + a_{1}X + a_{2}X^2$$

where $X$ is an indeterminate variable is an abuse of notation. Is $X^2$ just $X_2$? Put it another way, what's the meaning of the power in that context.

Comment: What do you mean by $X_2$?

Comment: @MattPressland The third element of an ordered list for example.

Comment: Like $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3 ...$

Comment: Oh, right. That's not what is happening - firstly, you only have one indeterminate, and secondly, there is a relationship between $X$ and $X^2$ that you want to capture, namely that $X\times X=X^2$. If you write a completely new variable instead of $X^2$, the notation doesn't make it clear that this relationship should hold.

Comment: @mdp, how is defined your symbol "$\times$"?

Comment: I think the question is legitimate, since the "powers of X" are often referred to as "placeholders", +1.

Comment: @user750041 By $\times$, I mean multiplication of polynomials, i.e. the multiplication operation in the ring of polynomials with coefficients in some other ring. (Or, if thinking about $X$ as an unknown element of this coefficient ring, I mean multiplication in that ring. The main point in either case is that $X^2$ has an algebraic relationship to $X$---it is the square of $X$---rather than just being another unknown.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$R[X]$ is a ring, it contains $X$, so you can multiply $X $ with itself. That's what $X^2$ means.

**ADD** Given a commutative ring $R$ with unity, we can consider the set of all sequences $(a_0,a_1,\ldots)$ in $R$ that are eventually zero, $R^{(\Bbb N)}$. We can add them coordinate-wise, and introduce multiplication as follows: if $A=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,0,\ldots)$ and $B=(b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m,0,\ldots)$, the $n$-th term of $AB$ is $\sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j$, that is $AB=(a_0b_0,a_1b_0+a_0b_1,a_2b_0+a_1b_1+a_2b_0,\ldots)$ -- this is exactly how we want polynomials to multiply out. If we identify $r\in R$ with $\hat r=(r,0,0,\ldots)$, we note that $\hat r A=(ra_0,ra_1,\ldots)$ using the definition above, $\hat 0=(0,0,\ldots)$ is the additive neutral element and $\hat 1 =(1,0,\ldots)$ is the multiplicative neutral element. One can see addition and multiplication are associative, and with a little work can obtain the remaining requirements to show $R^{(\Bbb N)}$ is made into a commutative ring with unity. Now set $X=(0,1,0,\ldots)$. Then using the definition of multiplication, we see $X^k=(0,0,\ldots,{1},\ldots,0,0,\ldots)$, where the $1$ is at the $k+1$-th place. Thus we can write any $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n,0,0,0,\ldots)$ as $a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\cdots+a_nX^n$ and by coordinatewise equality, we have $a_0+a_1X\cdots+a_nX^n$ and $b_0+b_1X+\cdots+b_mX^m$ are equal iff $n=m$ and $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.  Note $R\ni r\to\hat r\in R[X]$ is an injective homomorphism, so $R$ is embedded as a subring of $R[X]$. Thus our ring is generated by $R(=\hat R)$ and $X$, and we call it the polynomial ring over $R$ in one indeterminate, and denote it accordingly as $R[X]$.

Answer (score 8):

I think there may be some confusion due to the usual notion of variables. It is vital to note that in $R[X]$, the $X$ variable does *not* stand for some undetermined member of $R$, the way polynomials are taught in beginning calculus. It's (sort of) okay to think of $X$ as some undetermined member of an equally undetermined $R$-algebra, though. But really, you should just think of $X$ as a letter, and monomials $X^2$, $X^3$, etc. as some expressions involving this letter. You don't care what they mean, other than that they must satisfy the multiplication rule $X^m\cdot X^n=X^{m+n}$. And then, a polynomial is a *formal linear combination* of these monomials, such as $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ with $a_k\in R$.

So what is a formal linear combination? Good question. Just think about it as an expression like the sum above. The important factor is that the expression uniquely defines the coefficients $a_k$. This is not a *theorem*, it is true *by definition*.

Finally, turn this set of polynomials into a ring (actually, an $R$-algebra) by defining sums and products via the expected formuale.

PS. There is also a category theoretic definition which may be more satisfying, if you know the requisite theory.

Answer (score 4):

It means exactly what it usually does--that is, $X\cdot X.$ Not knowing what $X$ is doesn't change that.

At some point, we may want to evaluate the polynomial by substituting some value in for our indeterminate $X,$ but until then, it's basically just a placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you may be wondering how to give *rigorous* meaning to the *indeterminates* $x^k$ in $R[x]$.

$R[x]\,$ may be constructed as the subring of linear maps on $R^{\Bbb N} = (r_0,r_1,r_2,\ldots)\,$ generated by the $\,r$-scalings $\ v \mapsto r v = (r v_0, r v_1, \ldots)$ and the shift map $\,v\mapsto xv = (0,v_0,v_1,\ldots).\,$ These form a *ring* with multiplication being composition of linear maps $\, (fg)v = f(gv),\,$
where $\,\ x^2(1,0,0,\ldots) =\, x(x(1,0,0,\ldots)) = x(0,1,0,0,\ldots)\  =\  (0,0,1,0,0,\ldots),\ $ $\,\ x^3(1,0,0,\ldots) = x(x^2(1,0,0,\ldots) = x(0,0,1,0,0\ldots) = (0,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots),\, \ldots\ $  so
$$ (a_n x^n+\cdots + a_1 x+ a_0)(1,0,0,\ldots) = (a_0,a_1,\ldots, a_n,0,0,\ldots)\qquad$$

This implies that two polynomials are equal iff they have the same coefficients, by comparing  their values on $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ as above.

**Remark** $ $ This is essentially a special case of the fact that every ring can be represented as  a subring of the *ring* of linear maps on its underlying additive group, a ring-theoretic analog of Cayley's theorem for groups. The *universal* aspects of this construction are better appreciated when one studies universal algebra, e.g. see George Bergman's notes. Then one can [*discover* this construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157094/242) in a natural manner, as a solution to a universal mapping problem, using fairly general principles. In particular, look up "van der Waerden's trick" (which, if memory serves correct, is discussed in Bergman's notes).

Answer (score 4):

Very much along the line of @BillDubuque’s response, I suggest this: Let $R$ be your given ring, and set up the set $\mathrm{Map}_0(\mathbb N,R)$, namely the set of all maps from the nonnegative integers $\mathbb N$ to $R$ that are zero at all but a finite number of members of $\mathbb N$. The addition is coordinatewise (pointwise, if you like), and multiplication proceeds this way:
$$
(f*g)(n)=\sum^\infty_{i=0}f(i)g(n-i)\,,
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are given elements of the set, taken to be zero at negative integers. This looks like an infinite sum, but in fact is finite, because of the finitariness of $f$ and $g$. Now we define $X$ to be the function that takes the value $1$ at $1$, zero everywhere else, it’s in our set, and consider $R$ to be contained in our set by sending the element $a\in R$ to the function that’s $a$ at $0$ and zero everywhere else. So, for instance, $aX^2$ is the function that’s $a$ at $2$ and zero everywhere else. Finally, rename our set $R[X]$.