# What does the $x$ in $K[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, foundations

**Formal definition:** Let $K$ be a fixed field. Then $$R:=\{(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}: a_i\in K, a_i = 0\text{ for almost all } i\in\mathbb N_0\}$$
together with the usual $+$ and $\cdot$ is a field, called the *polynomial field*.

**Idea:** A *polynomial* is an expression of the form $a_n x^n +a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\dots a_2 x^2+ a_1x + a_0$, where $x$ denotes a variable and the coefficients $a_i$ are elements of $K$. For example $4x^3 + 8x^2 - x + 2$ is a polynomial (if $K=\mathbb R$). One can think of a sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N_0} \in R$ as representing the polynomial where $a_i$ is the coefficient in front of $x^i$. Thus our example from above $4x^3 + 8x^2 - x + 2$ is represented by  the sequence $(2, -1, 8, 4, 0, 0, \dots)$.

**Question:** I've often seen that people say "let $x$ be a symbol" in the formal definition and go on saying that they denote the set that I call $R$ by $K[x]$. I don't understand this, because in the formal definition there does never occur any variable $x$! Is the notation $K[x]$ chosen just for psychological reasons (like: "we think of the elements as being polynomial expressions that contain variables")? Or is $x$ treated as a parameter in the definition: "for every given field $K$ and every symbol $x$ we define $K[x]$ to be …". But in this case: what is a "variable"? and why doesn't the definition of $K[x]$ contain an $x$?

Comment: You can think $ x $ as $(0,1,0,0, \ldots) $.

Comment: More precisely $\,x\,$ is a symbol means that $\,x\,$ is *transcendental* over $\,R,\,$ i,e. $\,x\,$ is not algebraic over $\,R,\,$ i.e. not the root of any nonzero polynomial with coef's in $\,R.\,$ That construction is the *universal* way to adjoin an element to a commutative ring $\,R,\,$ i.e. it yields a commutative ring containing $\,R\,$ and $\,x\,$ which satisfies only the properties that are consequences of the commutative ring axioms, i.e. it is the "freest" or most general way to adjoin an element, captured algebraically in the universal mapping property of a polynomial ring.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/157094/242) for much further discussion on this and related topics (including other ways to construct polynomial rings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition, $x$ is simply the sequence $(0,1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$.

Some computations leads to: $$x^k=(\delta_{i,k+1})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots).$$
Namely, $x^k$ is the sequence with zeroes everywhere except at the $(k+1)$ position. Notice that any sequence of $R$ can be written as a finite linear combination over $K$ of elements in $\{x^k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. This fact is written: $$R=K[x].$$

Comment: Aight, so it's just a notational convention and nothing "deep" behind it.