# quotient group inheritance of some properties from original group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let us say that there is the group with addition modulo 6:

$G = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $N = \{0,3 \}$.

Then the quotient group $G/N$ would be $G/N = \{ \{0,3\}, \{1,4 \}, \{2,5\} \}$.

According to my sources, they say that as $N$ is normal subgroup, $G/N$ must be also group.
As the group $G$ is abelian, according to my sources (Wikipedia and textbook), they say that $G/N$ must be abelian group.

The question is, by quotient group $G/N$ being group, is group operation done by assuming that in the example, $0$ and $3$ are treated same, $1$ and $4$ are treated same and $2$ and $5$ are treated same? And abelian-ness can be checked by adding $(3+4) \pmod 6 = (4+3) \pmod 6 = 1 = 4?$

Or is this something else?

Comment: Yeah, essentially you are right that you have to treat them the same. So, for example, using the fact that $1$ and $4$ are the same we have $1+2=3\text{ mod }6$ while $4+2=0\text{ mod }6$ and this makes sense as $0$ and $3$ are treated the same. You should realise though that what is really going on is that you are working $\text{mod }3$.

Comment: You may find interesting [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332972/working-with-equivalence-classes-and-quotient-sets/332975) question about quotient sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something else: in the quotient you have *equivalence classes* which you will multiply (sum) according to the rules you were surely told. There are no more *mere elements* as in the mother group, yet it is always possible to pick up some representative from each class andwork with it...

This subject is better understood in calss, with a decent blackboard and some chalk, and doing many examples, but in your case we can say, for example, that

$$\{1,4\}+\{2,5\}=\{0,3\}\iff \bar 1+\bar 2=\bar 0$$

where the bar above means that we'reworking the equiv. class, not merely with the bare elements.

Comment: The point here is that elements which are in the same equivalence classes are "treated the same". Equivalence classes just formalise this.

Comment: Yes, but the operation is not more modulo $\,6\,$ , as my example shows, and this is what the OP asked, among other things.