# Axiomatic justification of the quotient set being a set rather than a class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Suppose we have an underlying set $S$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ defined on $S$ inducing the partition $S\backslash\sim=\{[s]_{\sim}:s\in S\}$ of $S$ known as the quotient set where $[s]_{\sim}$ is the equivalence class of $s$ (non-empty since $s\in[s]_{\sim}$ always holds) so that all $t,u\in[s]_{\sim}$ satisfy $t\sim u$.

Clearly to me (by this I mean I suppose intuitively) $S\backslash\sim$ is a class since it's elements are sets (subsets of $S$). I struggle with the formalities of justifying $S\backslash\sim$ is a set, whereas on this site I have seen others struggling with the reverse, that is to show or justify $S\backslash\sim$ is a class: for instance [a question about equivalence classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332972/working-with-equivalence-classes-and-quotient-sets)

I am not a set theorist, but do try to follow the very introductory pages of Thomas Jech (Set Theory, 2003, Springer) to keep myself vaguely aware of the axioms of ZF or ZFC, and am guessing these considerations are needed here to resolve my confusion? I am a little cavalier below in my applications of logic so please do forgive me for this, but I want to check how far off the mark I am here.

**My attempt;**

For all $B\in S\backslash\sim$ define $\psi(B)$ to take the value 1 if all pairs $s,t\in B$ satisfy $s\sim t$ *and* all points $u\in S\backslash B$ satisfy $u\not\sim s$ for all $s\in B$, and zero if not. I think this definition ensures $B\in S\backslash\sim$ if and only if $\psi(B)=1$ . Then according to Jech $\mathcal{C}$ is a *class*;

$$\mathcal{C}:=\{X:\psi(X)\}$$

I am guessing this means all members $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ satisfy $\psi(X)=1$ but for some reason this was not specified (maybe too obvious, although it does not seem too much effort to do this for clarity). Furthermore I have made $X$ as uppercase since I am obsessed with making it clear when $X$ is a set or $x$ is an element of a set, but I see many set theorists don't seem to bother with this (which does not help me at all). Note that $X$ in the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ seems to come "from nowhere", i.e. I would be tempted to write

$$\mathcal{C}:=\{X\subseteq S:\psi(X)\}$$

I am vaguely aware this change might be a big deal, that is assuming there is some "parent set" from which to draw elements from (in Russell's paradox and the set of all sets this concept seems to be crucial?). In the above I am intending $\phi$ to be a *property* without *parameters*, but again Jech is rather vague so I am doing this intuitively. Finally the so called "schema of separation" axiom states that $Y$ defined below is a *set* if $\phi$ is a property;

$$Y=\{u\in X:\psi(u)\}$$

I am lost here as to whether $X$ is a set or a class since I would write the set $Y$ exists if $\phi$ is a property and $X$ is a class;

$$Y=\{B\in X:\psi(B)=1\}$$

**So my question is essentially is $Y=S\backslash \sim$ the justification for $S\backslash \sim$ being a set?**

---

SOME EDITS: In response to comments I use the schema of replacement. I also refine/update my first attempt at defining a property $\psi$. To summarise I think I have shown the quotient set $S\backslash \sim$ is both a *class* and a *set* in the "proper" set theory world of ZFC?

Intuitively I was always happy $S\backslash \sim$ is a class but did not realise I had to justify this when using axiomatic set theory (ZFC has only sets). Given I am now aware of the axioms a little more, I am still surprised how difficult it is to show $S\backslash \sim$ is a set (if we start from the premise it is a class).

Appreciate any further corrections/insights from the set theorists out there.

**Binary relations as function**

For clarity of notation write $S\backslash \sim = S_{\sim}$. Define

\begin{align}
\phi_{\sim}:\hspace{5pt}S&\longrightarrow S_{\sim}\\
\phi_{\sim}(s)&\mapsto [s]_{\sim}
\end{align}

Now $\phi_{\sim}:S\longrightarrow S_{\sim}$ is a function if $\phi_{\sim}(s)=f(t)$ holds whenever $s=t$, or equivalently as per Jech p11 if $R_{\phi_{\sim}}$ is a binary relation on $S\times S_{\sim}$ then $R_{\phi_{\sim}}$ is a function if $(s,B),(s,C)\in R$ imply $B=C$.

The following $R_{\phi_{\sim}}$

\begin{align*}
    R_{\phi_{\sim}}=\left\{(s,B)\in S\times S_{\sim}:\phi_{\sim}(s)=B\right\}
\end{align*}

is a function because it satisfies $(s,B),(s,C)\in R_{\phi_{\sim}}$ implies $B=C$: since $B,C\in S_{\sim}$ then $B=[b]_{\sim}$ and $C=[c]_{\sim}$ for some $b,c\in S$ and hence $(s,B),(s,C)\in R_{\phi_{\sim}}$ implies $\phi_{\sim}(s)=[b]_{\sim}$ and $\phi_{\sim}(s)=[c]_{\sim}$. But $s\in [s]_{\sim}$ and so $\phi_{\sim}(s)=[s]_{\sim}$. Thus $[s]_{\sim}=[b]_{\sim}=[c]_{\sim}$ holds, or equivalently $[s]_{\sim}=B=C$.

Jech (2003) calls the more familiar (to me anyway) mapping notation $\phi$ the "standard" notation which are obviously linked in the following way;

\begin{align*}
    \forall (s,B)\in S\times S_{\sim}:\hspace{10pt}(s,B)\in R_{\phi_{\sim}}\Longleftrightarrow \phi_{\sim}(s)=B
\end{align*}

---

**The quotient set as a class using properties in ZFC?**

Firstly redefining the property $\psi$;

\begin{align*}
\psi(X)=1\Longleftrightarrow \forall x\in X: (x,B)\in R_{\phi_{\sim}}\text{ some }B\in S_{\sim}
\end{align*}

For any $X\subseteq S$ this property states $\psi(X)=1$ if and only if $\phi(x)=B$ for all $x\in X$ for some $B\in S_{\tau}$ (equivalently $\phi_{\sim}(x)=B$ for all $x\in B$ for some $B\in S_{\tau}$).

Then from page 5 of Jech, $\mathcal{C}$ is the *class* of all sets with $\psi(X)=1$

$$\mathcal{C}:=\{X:\psi(X)\}$$

I am not sure where the sets $X$ are drawn from (I am tempted to write $X\in 2^{S}$ but I sense not saying this is important rather than just more compact?)

$S_{\sim}=\mathcal{C}$;

Choose any $X\in\mathcal{C}$. Then $\phi_{\sim}(x)=B$ for all $x\in B$ for some $B\in S_{\tau}$. Suppose $s\in B$ for some $s\in S$. Then $\phi_{\sim}(x)=[s]_{\sim}$ for all $x\in B$ for some $[s]_{\sim}\in S_{\tau}$ implying $X\subseteq [s]_{\sim}$. Now choose any $x\in[s]_{\sim}$, meaning $\phi_{\sim}(x)=[s]_{\sim}$ is true implying $(x,[s]_{\phi})\in R_{\phi_{\sim}}$. Since this holds for all $x\in [s]_{\phi}$ we have $\psi([s]_{\phi})=1$ and thus $[s]_{\sim}\subseteq X$. Conclude $X=[s]_{\sim}$ and hence that $\mathcal{C}\subseteq S_{\sim}$ is true.

Conversely choose $[s]_{\phi}\in S_{\sim}$ which means for all $t\in[s]_{\phi}$ that $\phi_{\sim}(t)=[s]_{\phi}$, or equivalently $(t,[s]_{\phi})\in R_{\phi}$, and hence $\psi([s]_{\phi})=1$ must hold, which implies $[s]_{\phi}\in\mathcal{C}$. Thus $S_{\sim}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ is true, implying $S_{\sim}=\mathcal{C}$.

**Thus $S_{\sim}$ is a class?**

---

**Axiom Schema of Replacement**

Define the 1-1 function $F:S_{\sim}\longrightarrow S_{\sim}$, $F([s]_{\sim})\mapsto [s]_{\sim}$ and the binary relation $R_{F}$

$$R_{F}=\left\{A\times B\in S_{\sim}\times S_{\sim}:F(A)\mapsto A \right\}$$

Then the injective nature of $F$ ensures $(A,B),(A,C)\in R_{F}$ imply $B=C=A$ and hence $R_{F}$ is a function (obviously the identity function) consisting of the cross products $[s]_{\sim}\times [s]_{\sim}$.

By the schema of replacement since $R_{F}$ is a function there exists a set $Y$

$$Y=\{B:(B,B)\in R_{F}\}=\{F(B):B\in S_{\sim}\}$$

Since $[s]_{\sim}\in S_{\sim}$ satisfies $([s]_{\sim},[s]_{\sim})\in R_{F}$ then $[s]_{\sim}\in Y$ and hence $S_{\sim}\subseteq Y$. Conversely $B\in Y$ satisfies $F(B)=B$ and $B\in S_{\sim}$, hence $Y\subseteq S_{\sim}$ and so $Y= S_{\sim}$

**Thus $S_{\sim}$ is a set?**

Comment: Umm, $S / {\sim}$ is a subset of $P(S)$; so shouldn't it be as simple as using the power set axiom, then the selection axiom / theorem schema?

Comment: Oh, or using the replacement axiom schema should work too.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That was my first thought as well, the image of the projection is a function as well by replacement.

Comment: @DanielSchepler many thanks for your reply (+1) for the suggestion. I am still working through a response which I may include as an edit, but am still in the dark as to how to flesh this out.

Comment: @VincentBatens Thanks for your reply. Sorry I have only just understood your comment (I think) after I updated my question. Is my use of the replacement schema applied to  the binary relation $R_{F}$ what you had in mind?

Comment: I will answer what I meant with my comment: Replacement means that if you have a function $F:V\to V$ then $\forall x F[x]\in V$ where $V$ is the universe and $F[x]=\{y\mid \exists z\in x:f(z)=y\}$ is the image of $F$ under $S$. Then take $F:V\to V:s\mapsto\begin{cases}[s]_\sim&\text{if }s\in S\\\varnothing &\text{if }s\notin S\end{cases}$. Replacement now gives that $F[S]=S/\sim$ is a set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @VincentBatens. In your mapping notation $x\mapsto [s]_{\sim}$ if $x\in S$ did you mean $x\mapsto [x]_{\sim}$ if $x\in S$? Then this mapping is my mapping $\phi_{\sim}:S\longrightarrow S_{\sim}$ in my question? Then your $F[S]$ becomes $\phi_{\sim}(S)$? Finally does $\phi_{\sim}$ need to be firstly proven to be a class (in Jech set theory book it does)?

Comment: Your mapping coïncides with mine if you restrict the domain to $S$. I haven't read the book you mention. Usually in set theory, the axioms say what kind of collections are sets. Classes are all collections of the form $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ for some first order sentence $\phi$ and are sometimes not even considered objects, but just terms, something purely formal. Every set is a class but you don't need to prove things are classes to prove that they are sets.

Comment: Thanks @VincentBatens for the clarification. Maybe the "class is a function" requirement appearing in Jech in the replacement schema is trivial in the sense (to my mind) most collections can be made into classes, and hence class can be erased from the axiom and more simply put "if F is a function there exists a set $F[x]$" as per your comment.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean. I mean $F$ is a class since it is of the form $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ where $\phi(x)$ is a sentence saying $x$ is an ordered pair with first element not in $S$ and second element the empty set or first element in $S$ and second element the equivalence class of the first element. It is a relation since it only consists of ordered pairs and it is a function since $\forall x,y,y'((x,y)\in F\land (x,y')\in F\Longrightarrow y=y')$

Comment: Thanks that clears things up for me: all functions are classes (as per your demonstration) but a class need not be a function. So I do think Jech has chosen to put classes in his axiom of replacement, but other versions omit this.