# What is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (as groups, their set structures and algebraic structures)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you please explain this with simple examples?

To me, their elements are same. Because if I divide $ k+m\Bbb{Z}$ by $ n$, then it gives any one of the elements of $ \Bbb{Z}_n$. So can I say  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ both are same? Or does it happen due to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic?

Also are their set structure same? (if not, then I suppose they are not same groups/rings.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288438/difference-between-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-and-mathbbz-n)

Comment: As far as I know, there's usually none. However $\Bbb Z_n$ may also denote the ring of fractions with denominator a power of $n$ (e.g. $\Bbb Z_{10}$ might denote the ring of decimal numbers).

Comment: Are you asking about groups or rings?  What is your definition of $\Bbb Z_n$? Your question might be reopened if your reply indicates it differs from the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque i asked about rings. yes this question was answered before but i didn't understand their logics.