# Modular arithmetic: What does $\oplus$ mean in the context of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What do $\oplus$ and $\ominus$ mean in the context of modular arithmetic mod $n$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_n$?  I'm familiar with using it as a bit-wise XOR operator, but in the context of mod $n$, this doesn't sound like it would make any sense.

I am told that this has a modular operator definition and that if $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ then $(a\ominus b) \oplus (b\ominus a) = 0$.  I don't want to know how to show this equality but I include it only give any helpful context about what might be expressed by these symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just to differentiate the 'normal' $+$, from the operation with modular numbers.

So: $[a]\oplus [b]:=[a+b]$. Note, that $\oplus$ adds 'sets' and $+$ adds numbers.

Comment: Whether or not the quotient ring elements are sets is an artefact of the particular construction of the quotient ring. The goal is to view the elements *abstractly* - as *atomic* elements of a new ring whose only essential properties are how the elements are related by the ring operations (so any internal element structure is ignored). For further discussion see  [the final two paragraphs here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118922/242)

Answer (score 0):

Onle likely possibility is that they denote addition and subtraction operations for integers $\!\bmod n,\,$ i.e. $\,a \oplus b  = (a\! +\! b)\bmod n,\,$  i.e.  perform integer addition $a+b\,$ then return its remainder $\bmod n\,$ (and analogously for subtraction).

It is also possible that they could represent the analogous operations in the quotient ring $\,\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z.\,$

Without any further context it's difficult to say further.