# Why are the elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$ of the form $ ax +b $. why not $(ax+b)+\langle x^2\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$$

**My question** : Why are  the  elements of   $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$   of the  form $ ax +b $. why not $(ax+b)+\langle x^2\rangle?$

**My thinking** :  I know that $R/A= \{r +A |r \in R\}$ where $R$ is  a ring and  $A$ is a  subring of $R$

I think elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2\rangle}$ are of the form  $(ax+b)+\langle x^2\rangle$ where $a ,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5$

**My confusion** :  Where  $x^2$ has gone ? What is the reason for omitting $\langle x^2\rangle$ from the  $(ax+b)+\langle x^2\rangle$?

Comment: Do polynomial division by $x^2$. You get a multiple of $x^2$ and a remainder of degree at most $1$. They are indeed of the form $ax+b+\langle x^2\rangle$. Abuse of notation is calling them by one representative $ax+b$.

Comment: The reason is simpler notation.

Comment: You are correct that the elements are of the form $(ax+b)+\langle x^2\rangle$ (use `\langle` and `\rangle` for these brackets by the way). A notation like "$\overline{ax+b}$" could have been used I guess.

Comment: okay@BrunoB ...

Comment: okay@NDB that means $x^2$  acts  like a modulus. Am i right ?

Comment: Is $A$ a subring of $R$? Shouldn't it be a two-sided ideal?

Comment: Yes@SineoftheTime  $A$ is  a subring of $R$

Comment: @SineoftheTime Take $R= \mathbb{Z}$  and $A=4\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @jasmine $4 \Bbb Z$ is the principal ideal generated by $4$, namely $4\Bbb Z=(4)$

Comment: Those remainders are (Euclidean) normal-form representatives of the cosets - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: For another well-known example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118922/242) for polynomial normal forms, and some related pedagogical remarks.

Answer (score 5):

When working with quotients, we often choose convenient representatives for the equivalence classes.  For instance, we might look at $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and think of it as $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with $+/\cdot$ modulo 5 instead of as the five cosets:
$$
\{\{\ldots, 0, 5, 10, \ldots\},\{\ldots, 1, 6, 11, \ldots\},\{\ldots, 2, 7, 12, \ldots\},\{\ldots, 3, 8, 13, \ldots\},\{\ldots, 4, 9, 14, \ldots\}\}.
$$
At the very least, it's less writing and everyone knowns what you mean.

The same thing is done in your example, where the linear polynomials are a collection of convenient representatives.

The same thing is done in, e.g. geometry/topology, where one might choose representatives $\{[x:y:1],[x:1:0], [1:0:0]\}$ for the projective plane instead of considering the collection of linear subspaces.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)

Comment: ...and I've been answering questions on and off for most of those years.  Just trying to help people when bored, use my PhD for something.  Obviously kids aren't going to do a literature search before asking questions, and I doubt server space is an issue.  Anyway, I've never read any of the policies of, well, anything, and I'm not going to start now.

Comment: @yoyo The goal is to organize the site so that the best answers to common questions are easy to locate, e.g. all on the same page. This will never occur if users continue to post duplicate answers to common questions. Such rampant duplication greatly *disorganizes* the site - devolving it into an ephemeral stream of low-quality fgitw answers rather than a library of "proofs from the book".